# How to define a constrained generic for Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following function:

```
export async function graphQLBase<T>(
  requestString: string,
  variables?: T
): Promise<any> {
  const sendRequest: TestGQLRequest = { query: requestString, variables };

  return supertest('http://localhost:7071')
    .post('/api/...')
    .send(sendRequest)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200);
}
```

I've given `graphQLBase` a generic to be able to get type safety when using the function elsewhere.  However, I'd like to go one step further and make it so that the use of the function with generic should always be of a type of object or `undefined`.  e.g. I should get some error feedback if I try to use the function as such: `graphQLBase<string>(...)`

Comment: Can you just replace `<T>` with `<T extends object>`, or does that not suit your needs? I wouldn't be surprised if that also allows functions, for example.

Comment: @Bbrk24 do you want to write the answer here with a link to [the docs for generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)?

Comment: Judging by the code, it would be more appropriate to use `extends Record<string, unknown>`. The constraint `extends object` actually constraints to [_anything non-primitive_](https://tsplay.dev/mppnXm)

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine Hence why I asked about functions. I saw a comment saying that this was what was intended, but I don't see it anymore. If the data is being encoded as JSON, for example, I might use [type-fest's JSONObject](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#json) type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.

As per [the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), you can use the word `extends` to specify a generic constraint. In this case, that would look like

```
export async function graphQLBase<T extends object>(
  requestString: string,
  variables?: T
): Promise<any> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I did end up using `Record<string, unknown>` to narrow the generic type down further.  But the real bit was in fact the `extends` that I was looking for here so thank you.